# What does "fire" mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In football context, the verb "fire" means to kick the ball with a lot of force. I think it's used very strangely here. "Fire Manchester City" doesn't make any sense at all. In other words, the two player fire their own team. How do you paraphase it?

> *Kevin De Bruyne and Phil Foden **fire** Manchester City past Bournemouth. Harry Kane **fires** England into the final.*

Comment: A useful resource is an etymological dictionary, that is, one that gives information on the origin of words. Fire as a verb "to fire a gun" is from the 1520s. By extension to fire other weapons such as a bow or a spear is from the 1580s.  https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=fire

Answer (score 2):

In general, "fire" means to shoot a bullet out of a gun.  It is from this general meaning that you get the metaphor about kicking a ball very hard.

But you can also make other metaphors about things being propelled quickly.  In these examples, the football teams have moved up the league table (and ahead of Bournemouth), or progressed into the finals.

It is commentator "[puff](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puff#Noun:%7E:text=(countable)%20A%20flamboyant%20or%20alluring%20statement%20of%20praise.)" to use the metaphor of the team being "fired past Bournemouth" etc. It probably suggests that these players scored a number of goals.  Perhaps in an exciting way - from long range, allowing for a bit of mixed metaphor: Kane "fired" the ball into the net, which "fired" English into the final. And now England are "fired up" (excited)...

Again, the point of learning from Football commentary is to listen for the general sense. Commentators are famous for talking nonsense, so trying to be analytical is rather ridiculous.

Comment: Your expalanation is excellant. Does that use apply with onther verbs, such as "blast, hammer, slam, thunder", etc? For example: Kevin De Bruine blasts/hammers, etc Man City against Bournemouht.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Read football commentary for adventures in using words, but don't try to analyse what they write.